# Read a ActiveX control using a PHP?

Tags: php, activex

I am not sure is it possible or not.I dont have any Idea on this.I am using one SDK with for the scanner scanning the document and getting the values.Now I want to access the SDK from my website to the local system.For that I want to read the ActiveX control using PHP?Is it possible to read the ActiveX control from PHP?Or do you have any idea on this please suggest me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the PHP faq here : [PHP can be used to access COM and DCOM objects on Win32 platforms.](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/faq.com.php)

```
<?php
$word = new COM("C:\docs\word.doc");
?>
```